# Método que retorna uma classe

Tags: c#, .net, método, reflexão

Estou tentando criar um método que recebe uma string e retorna uma instância da classe com o nome passado, exemplo: "Calculadora", vai me retornar uma instância da classe "Calculadora" (Caso a mesma existir), estou com problema na hora de setar qual o tipo ele retorna, pois pelo que pesquisei eu preciso passar o tipo pro método também. Tentei: `Type Tipo = Type.GetType("NomeDaClasse");` e depois passando `var x = RetornaClasse<Tipo>("Calculadora");` mas sem sucesso. (Na verdade nem consigo setar o método pra tentar usar.

```
static T RetornaClasse<T>(string nome) where T : class
{
    return (T)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(nome);
}
```

Uso: o retorno desse método vai ser parâmetro para essa **Classe Genérica:**

```
public class Generico<T> where T : class
{
    public T Objeto { get; set; }

    public string ListarAtributos()
    {
        var p = Objeto.GetType().GetProperties();
        string atributos = String.Empty;

        foreach (PropertyInfo pop in p) // Lista de atributos
            atributos += (String.Concat("[", pop.Name, "] = [", pop.GetValue(Objeto, null), "]\n"));

        return atributos;
    }

    public string[] ListarMetodos()
    {
        var m = Objeto.GetType().GetMethods();
        string[] metodos = new string[m.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
            metodos[i] = String.Concat(i, " [+] ", m[i].Name, "\n");
        return metodos;
    }

    // TODO: Setar atributos, usar métodos
}
```

**Solução:**

```
static object RetornaClasse(string nome)
{
    var classe = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == nome);
    var instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(classe);
    return instancia;
}
```

Comment: O tipo está no mesmo assembly, ou de um terceiro?

Comment: No mesmo assembly.

Comment: Teria como editar a questão, indicando como você pretende usar o retorno do método?

Comment: Se os métodos e propriedades serão acessados via reflexão, então não há necessidade do parâmetro genérico.

Comment: Acho que a confusão está nessa linha `T RetornaClasse<T>(string nome) where T : class` ... isso não retorna uma classe por si, mas sim uma instância de um objeto T, em que T só pode ser uma classe e não uma struct. Ou seja, ao chamar o método `RetornaClasse` só será possível indicar classes como parâmetro genérico, e não structs: `RetornaClasse<string>()` é válido pois `string` é classe, `RetornaClasse<int>` não é válido pois `int` é struct.

Comment: Segui seu conselho e tirei o parâmetro <T> da classe Genérica e mudei o atributo para object, deixei o método retornando um object, só que agora ele instancia mas não consigo usar o construtor vazio da classe "Calculadora", como eu instancio ele com o construtor vazio (pra vim zerada os parâmetros), EDIT: consegui!

Comment: É usando o método `Activator.CreateInstance(tipo)`.

Comment: Isso que eu fiz! Obrigado Miguel! :)

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo de como usar um objeto usando reflexão, e usando `dynamic`... acho que será do seu interesse verificar o uso do dynamic nesse caso, pois facilita bastante.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se o tipo estiver no mesmo Assembly que estiver em execução, pode fazer assim:

```
var t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "Calculadora");
```

E depois usar o tipo para criar uma nova instância:

```
var objectOfType = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Exemplo de um programa totalmente funcional, usando argumento genérico, e LINQ para facilitar um pouco:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var computador = GetInstanciaDoTipo<Computador>("Calculadora");

        var usarReflexao = new UsandoReflexaoParaAcessarObjeto();
        usarReflexao.Objeto = computador;
        var resultado1 = usarReflexao.TentarSomar();
        var resultado2 = usarReflexao.SomarUsandoDynamic();
        var resultado3 = computador.Somar(1, 2);
    }

    private static T GetInstanciaDoTipo<T>(string nomeTipo)
    {
        return
            (T)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.Name == nomeTipo)
                .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                .First();
    }

    abstract class Computador
    {
        public abstract int Somar(int a, int b);
    }

    class Calculadora : Computador
    {
        public override int Somar(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Esta classe usa reflexão para acessar o objeto, seja lá qual o tipo dele.
    /// Também há um método usando dynamic, para exemplificar como é mais fácil usar dynamic do que reflection,
    /// quando queremos executar algo dinamicamente.
    /// </summary>
    public class UsandoReflexaoParaAcessarObjeto
    {
        public object Objeto { get; set; }

        public int? TentarSomar()
        {
            if (this.Objeto != null)
            {
                var type = this.Objeto.GetType();
                var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Somar");
                var result = methodInfo.Invoke(this.Objeto, new object[] { 1, 2 });
                return (int)result;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public int? SomarUsandoDynamic()
        {
            if (this.Objeto != null)
            {
                dynamic dyn = this.Objeto;
                return dyn.Somar(1, 2);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E como ficaria isso no método? Pergunto pois eu estou tentando fazer porque tenho uma classe genérica que recebe uma classe e esse método serviria como parâmetro da mesma, dessa forma que você fez usando var, o C# não deixa eu passar como parâmetro pra classe (Ele não sabe que a var vai ser um tipo classe). `public class Generico<T> where T : class`

Comment: Fiz um método `GetInstanciaDoTipo` que permite passar como parâmetro genérico um T do qual a classe sendo buscada herda ou implementa... é isso? Eu não entendi muito bem ainda em que contexto você quer usar o retorno deste método.

Comment: Postei a classe Genérica que falei, meu objetivo Miguel é estudar Reflection, nessa classe Genérica eu vou criar métodos que vão usar os métodos das classes passadas, setar atributos, eu quero dar ao usuário a liberdade de escolher a classe que ele deseja interagir, por isso estou tentando pegar o nome e depois instanciar ela pra usar na classe Genérica.